# Trigger logic and roll up summary field

Tags: apex, trigger

Basically, I want to insert a billing line (for the tax) on my billing after inserting the billing (if there exists a tax rate on the account). 
Simple, however the calculation for this billing line depends on the total amount on billing (AcctSeed__Total__c).

Since the total is a roll up summary field, it is not updated (so the amount=0).
How can I use trigger to achieve this? Can this be done using trigger.old?
Will the roll up summary field be updated in trigger.old after insert trigger?

I know one approach is to up use AGGREGATE RESULT on my billing lines to get that total, but is there another way?

```
trigger CreateTaxLine on AcctSeed__Billing__c (after insert) {

List <id> bids= new List <id>();
List <AcctSeed__Billing_Line__c> blcs= new List<AcctSeed__Billing_Line__c> ();
for (AcctSeed__Billing__c b: Trigger.new) {
    bids.add(b.id);
}
// SOQL TO get billings with tax 
  List <AcctSeed__Billing__c> bls = [Select a.AcctSeed__Total__c,a.AcctSeed__Date__c, a.AcctSeed__Customer__r.Account_Tax__r.AcctSeed__Tax_Rate__c,a.AcctSeed__Customer__r.Account_Tax__r.AcctSeed__Rate__c, a.AcctSeed__Customer__c,
                                     a.AcctSeed__Customer__r.Account_Tax__r.AcctSeed__Tax_Rate__r.Id, a.AcctSeed__Customer__r.Account_Tax__r.AcctSeed__Tax_Rate__r.AcctSeed__Revenue_GL_Account__c
                                     From AcctSeed__Billing__c a 
                                     where a.AcctSeed__Customer__r.Account_Tax__r.AcctSeed__Tax_Rate__c!=null AND id=:bids  ];
   //New billing line for the billings that should have a tax item. 
    for (AcctSeed__Billing__c bl: bls){
        if(bl.AcctSeed__Customer__r.Account_Tax__r.AcctSeed__Rate__c!=null && bl.AcctSeed__Total__c!=null)
        {
            system.debug('**********'+bl.AcctSeed__Total__c);
            system.debug('********** TAX RATE'+bl.AcctSeed__Customer__r.Account_Tax__r.AcctSeed__Rate__c);
            AcctSeed__Billing_Line__c blc= new AcctSeed__Billing_Line__c ();
                blc.AcctSeed__Billing__c= bl.Id;
                blc.AcctSeed__Hours_Units__c= 1;
            blc.AcctSeed__Rate__c= (bl.AcctSeed__Total__c)*(bl.AcctSeed__Customer__r.Account_Tax__r.AcctSeed__Rate__c);
               blc.AcctSeed__Product__c= bl.AcctSeed__Customer__r.Account_Tax__r.AcctSeed__Tax_Rate__r.Id;
               blc.AcctSeed__Revenue_GL_Account__c= bl.AcctSeed__Customer__r.Account_Tax__r.AcctSeed__Tax_Rate__r.AcctSeed__Revenue_GL_Account__c;
            blc.AcctSeed__Date__c= bl.AcctSeed__Date__c;

             blcs.add(blc);


        }

    }
    //insert the billing lines
    insert (blcs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work....the workaround was to have a conditional if statement...
so before the roll-up field is populated (after the record is saved), it has a default value (0 in my case), so to prevent an infinite loop of (after update), 
 I placed this condition: Trigger.oldmap.get(bls.id).AcctSeed__Total__c==0

Since total__c is my roll-up field for billing and after the record gets saved, its old value ==0, but after the second iteration of trigger, the old value gets updated, thus preventing an infinite self referential trigger. Cheers ! :)

Comment: Just hope that no one creates a billing for a "zero" amount..lol.